# Beautiful Soup get only string from soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do you get only HTML string from a tag with multiple children with Beautiful Soup?

I'm trying to get the population of different nations with Beautiful Soup, but the  tag with the population info also has a bunch of other tags so soup.table.tr.string returns None, is there a way to get only '1.411.750.000 (2022)'?

Here is the HTML I'm trying to parse (from https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksrepublik_China)

```
<td>
 1.411.750.000 (2022)
 <small>
  (<a href="/wiki/Liste_von_Staaten_und_Territorien_nach_Einwohnerzahl#Liste" title="Liste von Staaten und Territorien nach Einwohnerzahl">1.</a>)
 </small>
 <sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-2">
  <a href="#cite_note-2">[2]</a>
 </sup>
</td>
```

This is my python code just in case

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Fischerei_und_Aquakultur_nach_L%C3%A4ndern')
s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for i in s.find_all('td'):
    if i.a:
        tr = requests.get(f"https://de.wikipedia.org{i.a.get('href')}")   
        ts = BeautifulSoup(tr.content, 'html.parser')

        print(f"https://de.wikipedia.org{i.a.get('href')}:")
        for j in ts.table.find_all('tr'):
            if j.td.b:
                if "Einwohnerzahl" in j.td.b:
                    print("population: ", j.find_all('td')[1].string)
                    break
```